# what was the reason for rape in greek myths and culture

Tags: greek, origins, zeus, mythohistory, aphrodite

Is the reason gods assaulted women because of Eros?

Did gods and mortals alike blame Eros for their act of "passion"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is rape featured so prominently in Greek mythology?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/why-is-rape-featured-so-prominently-in-greek-mythology)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mythology and Folklore! Interesting question. Please look at the question provided by Chenmunka to see if that might answer your question, if not that's also ok.

@Chenmunka I think some can be answered with that question and its answer. But I also think the Eros part is interesting and unique enough that it might constitute getting its own answer.

Comment: There are questions to be asked here. Are you asking for Greek sources only, or Greek Roman? There are also some researches that assume that Aphrodite is a later inclusion of a more ancient godess, like Astarte, Isthar. Having that in mind, please clarify me what sources are accepted for an answer and I will give you one.